# Using extern keyword to call functions

Tags: c, extern, storage-class-specifier

I want to call functions defined in test.c from other.c.

Can I `extern` the `function1` to call it? Also, do I have to use `extern` in `function2` and `function3`, which are being called by `function1`?

**other.c**

```
extern function1();
function1();
```

**test.c**

```
void function1()
{
    function2();
    function3();
}

void function2()
{

}

void function3()
{

}
```

Comment: Replace `extern function1();` by `void function1();`

Comment: ... and no, you don't need to care about `function2()` and `function3()` if you dont want to call them from `other.c`.

Comment: I see. I want function1 to be able to call them, which it should be able to, correct?

Comment: the normal thing to do is to create other.h, and place `void function1()` in there. And then `#include other.h` in test.c

Comment: `extern` is only needed for shared data, not for functions

Comment: In `test.c`: if `function2()` is declared _before_ you use it (this is not the case here) then you don't need to do anything. Otherwise you need to declare `void function2();` and `void function3();` _before_  using them (that is before `void function1()`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually every function by default is extern :) - unless you declare them to be not :). It is enough if you have the prototype before the first call;

```
int xxx(int, int, float, double);  // prototype


int main(void)
{
  int x,y;
  float z;
  double v;

  xxx(x,y,z,v);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Function can be in the another .c file. You need to include the object file to the linking.

```
int xxx(int a, int b, float c, double d)
{
  int result;
  /* do something */

  return result;
}
```

Comment: @Filip Kočica :( . if you do it, you know what you want to archive. Comment is completely off topic

Answer (score 4):

Function declarations are "by-default" `extern`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function **has no storage-class specifier**, its linkage
>   is determined exactly **as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`.** [...]

So, you don't need to be explicit about it.

You need to compile the translation units aka source files (into object files) and then link them together to build the executable. That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

`extern` simply tells us that it is defined somewhere else. And you are using it in the file you are writing the `extern`. But functions are by default extern. So you need not be explicit about it.

Comment: @PeterJ_01.: I got brave and explained more about objkects to show differences? I can remove if you tell me that they dont conform to this answer

Answer (score 2):

You use `extern` to declare symbols which are *external* to the current [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (roughly a single source file with all its included header files).

## Simple example

The first source file `test1.c`

```
extern void function1(void);  // "Import" a function from another translation unit

int main(void)
{
    function1();  // Can call the declared function
}
```

Then the second source file `test2.c`:

```
void function2(void)
{
    // Do something
}

void function1(void)
{
    function2();  // No extern needed, it's declared (and defined)
                  // in the same translation unit
}
```

As you can see the function `function2` doesn't need any `extern` declaration anywhere. It is used only in `test2.c` so only `function1` needs to know about it.

However in `test1.c` the `main` function needs to know about `function1` because it is called, then we make a *forward declaration* of the function prototype. This is done using the `extern` keyword. *But* for declaring functions the `extern` keyword isn't actually needed, as they are always considered "external" (as noted by Peter).

Comment: functions are always extern. Variables are not.